# Network not working after new motherboard installation (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, motherboard

So I installed a new motherboard with an existing Ubuntu install and now my network won't connect (wired).

The first help thread I read suggested deleting `/etc/udev/70-persistent-net.rules` and then rebooting, saying that this file would get recreated on startup.  I tried this and rebooted several times but no replacement file is created.

Other recommendations include changing the `eth0` string in `/etc/udev/70-persistent-net.rules` to the new `eth`, but they don't say where I can see what the new `eth` # is for the new motherboard.

ifconfig also shows no ethernet adapters available.

```
lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK running MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:1520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
RX packets:1520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:119430 (119.4KB) TX bytes:119430 (119.4 KB)
```

New motherboard is a Gigabyte Z170XP-SLI, if that matters.

As per [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270582/how-to-fix-networking-after-installing-a-new-cpu-motherboard) I've checked `/var/log/syslog` but have found no `udev[nnn]: renamed network interface ethN to ethX` lines.

**dmidecode | grep -b3 -a3 -i "Eth"** yields

```
14986-Handle 0x003B, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
15023-Onboard Device
15038-  Reference Designation:  Onboard LAN
15075:  Type: Ethernet
15091-  Status: Enabled
15108-  Type Instance: 1
15126-  Bus Address: 0000:00:19.0
```

and 
**dmesg | grep -i "Eth"** yields:

```
[    1.849863] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

Comment: I wonder if your system is loading a suitable network driver.  Can you provide the output of sudo lspci ?

Comment: @davidgo In `lspci` I see an entry that reads: `00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15b8 (rev 31)`

Comment: Try `udevadm trigger`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae That didn't give any output, didn't fail but didn't write anything to the console.

Comment: And now does `ip link show` show anything apart from `lo`?

Comment: Also, can you provide the output of  dmidecode | grep -b3 -a3 'Eth'  adn dmesg | grep "Eth"

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Nope, just lo.

Comment: @davidgo Not sure if I got this command right.  All I got was `grep: adn: No such file or directory` and `grep: dmesg: No such file or directory`

Comment: That should have been:  **dmidecode | grep -b3 -a3 -i 'Eth'** and **dmesg | grep -i "Eth"**

Comment: @MariusMatutiae updated original answer with the output from those commands.

Comment: is the dmicode program installed on your system?